# Entity Framework tries to create database on production server while it already exists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, production

I have developed a an Api web Application which users entity framework as an ORM. Recently our production server has changed and we moved our application. we have already restored the database on server and set the connection string Integrated Security to false. we have provided the username and password that we were given. but when we try to call one of our Api's application encounters following error :

CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I have searched for this problem but none of the solutions were practical for me.
the solutions were :

1. Change Integrated Security to false and user sql authentication. (I'm already doing that)
2. give dbcreator and sysadmin to the user. (We don't have access to that on production server)

Comment: can you share your connection string.

Comment: my connection string wont work ouside that server. still share it ?

Comment: Has your db _migraton history table? You need to full backup from old database and restore to new database. I did it so many times and I didn't get this error.

Comment: i suggest you test this stuff before messing with prod stuff.., if the migraton table is missing it will try create, you should be testing this stuff before... trying on prod tho

Comment: Yes. I restored full backup from previous production server

Comment: this stuff were working absolutely fine on previous prod server. all we did was transferring files and database